# Form input border-radius not working properly

Tags: html, css, forms

I am testing with CSS on forms and bumped on this: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/z4a4G/1/

As I try to make the form inputs round-cornered, they assume the whole input as a round object.

```
border-radius:50%;
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this correctly?
Why does this happen?

Comment: What is the result that you are expecting ?

Comment: You no longer have to use the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes : [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving it a `px` value works best in this scenario. Percentage is typically used when creating shapes (in your case, a circle)

```
input{
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

I believe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/z4a4G/3/) is what you're going for. Giving your borders a percentage will mean that they will all look different based on the width and height. Using `px` gives it a consistent look.

Comment: Yes, but what if the width and height are variable?

Comment: I've really only seen percentage radius when creating shapes. Giving your borders a percentage will mean that they will all look different based on the width and height. Using `px` gives it a consistent look

Comment: It looks better to have one consistent border curve than to have a large number of non-matching radius'.

Answer (score 2):

In your case I think you have to enter border-radius in pixels like as follows:

> border-radius:5px;

because you gave too much high radius that is why your input box is just looking like a round object & 5px is sufficient in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

will give you a circle, not just a rounded border. Doing this with non-square elements can have some strange eliptical shapes. Set the values using px or em, or choose a much smaller % to achieve something that still resembles a form field.